# Передача доп.параметров в System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Как передать в `MatchEvaluator` доп.параметры. Сейчас я использую статические переменные для передачи, но как-то это некрасиво

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
//Наш подстановщик MatchEvaluator
protected static string ReplaceForDisplayString(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m)
{
  //Что-то что использует передаваемый параметр
}
//Основной код
string pattern = @"\{([0-9]{1,}|[P]{1})\}";//Паттерн не важен, он может быть и другим
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
//Тут запускаем подстановщик по регулярке, 
//однако в подстановщик нужно передать параметр, 
//который будет там использоваться
string newStr = rgx.Replace(str, new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceForDisplayString));
```

UPD: сейчас у меня что-то типа:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
//Вот это параметр я передаю как-то по топорному
protected static object parameter = null; 
protected static string ReplaceForDisplayString(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m)
{
  //Тут я его как-то использую
  return parameter.ToString();
}
string pattern = @"\{([0-9]{1,}|[P]{1})\}";//Паттерн не важен, он может быть и другим
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
parameter = "abcd";
string newStr = rgx.Replace(str, new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceForDisplayString));
```

Comment: что ты имеешь ввиду под доп параметрами?

Comment: например int, char или SqlTransaction это неважно, нужно передать это в ReplaceForDisplayString

Comment: Так - http://ideone.com/Zhv4z1?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew не уверен, мне вкратце надо передать `int` и `SqlTransaction`

Comment: Не проще ли мой вариант?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew там код большой... условия и т.д.

Comment: Обычно у меня там не больше 2-х строк. Тогда ясно.

Comment: А как может быть связана SqlTransaction с заменой в строке?

Comment: @Grundy изменения из базы подтягиваются под снапшотовской транзакцией

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как насчет?

```
protected static string ReplaceForDisplayString(Match m, string parameter)
{
  return parameter.ToString();
}


string pattern = @"\{([0-9]{1,}|[P]{1})\}";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string newStr = rgx.Replace(str, m => ReplaceForDisplayString(m, "abcd"));
```

Как верно заметил Grundy - `new MatchEvaluator()` можно опустить.

Подробнее про [лямбда-выражения](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb397687(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: хммм... сейчас попробую

Comment: по идее `new MatchEvaluator` можно опустить

Comment: Ага, и вообще весь `ReplaceForDisplayString`.

Comment: Отлично, все сработало

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, не, если там тело большое, то лучше оставить :-)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew =)) не думаю, он у меня на 20 строк...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew насколько я понял, этот код - чисто ради примера. Дмитрий собирается пихать туда `int` и `SqlTransaction`, поэтому это хорошее решение вынести это в отдельный метод.